# Lua split string using specific pattern

Tags: lua

i need to split each row of a input file using the specific pattern " - ". I'm not so far from solution but my code actually splits also single spaces. Each row of the file is formatted as follow:

`NAME - ID - USERNAME - GROUP NAME - GROUP ID - TIMESTAMP`

name field may have spaces, same as group name and timestamp, for example a row like that

`LUCKY STRIKE - 11223344 - @lucky - CIGARETTES SMOKERS - 44332211 - 11:42 may/5th`

is valid.
So these tokenized values should be stored inside a table.
Here is my code:

```
local function splitstring(inputstr)
  sep = "(%s-%s)"
  local t={} ; i=1
  for str in string.gmatch(inputstr, "([^"..sep.."]+)") do
      t[i] = str
      i = i + 1
  end
  print("=========="..t[1].."===========")
  print("=========="..t[2].."===========")
  print("=========="..t[3].."===========")
  return t
end
```

when i run it, puts "lucky" in first field, strike in second field, the id inside third field. 
Is there a way to store "lucky strike" inside first field, parsing ONLY by pattern specified?
Hope you guys could help me.

p.s. I already see the lua manual but didn't help me so much...

Comment: `t = {inputstr:gsub('%s+%-%s+','\0'):match(('.-(%Z+)'):rep(6))}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with what you have.

Firstly, `-` is a repetition symbol in Lua patterns:
http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.4.1

You need to use `%-` to get a literal `-`.

We're not done: The resulting gmatch call is `string.gmatch(inputstr, "[^%s%-%s]+")`. Since your separator pattern is inside [], it's a character class. It says "Give me all the things that aren't a space or a -, and be as greedy as you can", which is why it stops at the first space character.

Your best bet is to do something like:

```
local function splitstring(inputstr)
  sep = "%-"
  local t={} ; i=1
  for str in string.gmatch(inputstr, "[^"..sep.."]+") do
      t[i] = str
      i = i + 1
  end
  print("=========="..t[1].."===========")
  print("=========="..t[2].."===========")
  print("=========="..t[3].."===========")
  return t
end
```

Which yields:

```
==========LUCKY STRIKE ===========
========== 11223344 ===========
========== @lucky ===========
```

... And now independently fix the problem of the spaces around the values.

Comment: This page from the manual gives a bunch of examples of how to trim the spaces from the ends of strings: http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringTrim

Comment: See the comment you just replied to?

Answer (score 4):

Here is another take:

```
s="LUCKY STRIKE - 11223344 - @lucky - CIGARETTES SMOKERS - 44332211 - 11:42 may/5th"    
s=s.." - "
for v in s:gmatch("(.-)%s+%-%s+") do
    print("["..v.."]")
end
```

The pattern reflects the definition of the field: everything until `-` surrounded by spaces. Here "everything" is implemented using the non-greedy pattern `.-`.To make this work uniformly, we add the separator to the end as well. Many pattern matching problems that use separators can benefit from this uniformity.

Comment: Bonus points for explaining how this works so OP doesn't have to get you to write all his Lua pattern code for him :P

Comment: @ChrisKitching, fair enough. I've added some explanation. Thanks for the nudge.