# Lua: How to start match after a character

Tags: lua, pattern-matching, string-matching

I'm trying to make a search feature that allows you to split a search into two when you insert a | character and search after what you typed.

So far I have understood how to keep the main command by capturing before the space.

An example being that if I type :ban user, a box below would still say :ban, but right when I type in a |, it starts the search over again.

```
:ba
:ba

:ban user|:at
:at

:ban user|:attention members|:kic
:kic
```

This code:

```
text=":ban user|:at"
text=text:match("(%S+)%s+(.+)")
print(text)
```

would still return ban.

Comment: Thanks for that quick patch-up!

Comment: I just do not understand what you expect to get with the `":ban user|:at"` input: `:at`, or `at`? See https://ideone.com/NJlJM3

Comment: I'm trying to get a match of after the final | character.

Comment: Then I guess you need `text=text:match(".*%|(.*)")`

Comment: Alright, seemed to manage to get it by using two :matches.
`a = string:match(".*%|(.*)")
a = a:match("(%S+)%s+(.+)")` Any idea on compacting that?

Comment: And it also seems to not work when there's no | to look for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to get a match of after the final | character.

Then you can use

```
text=":ban user|:at"
new_text=text:match("^.*%|(.*)") 
if new_text == nil then new_text = text end
print(new_text)
```

See the [Lua demo](https://ideone.com/OmngAz)

**Explanation**:

- `.*` - matches any 0+ characters *as many as possibl* (in a "greedy" way, since the whole string is grabbed and then backtracking occurs to find...)
- `%|` - the last literal `|`
- `(.*)` - match and capture any 0+ characters (up to the end of the string).

Comment: The problem with Lua patterns is that you cannot define an optional sequence. Thus, we need to use `if-else` here with a `new_text` variable to restore the original `text` value when a `nil` is returned.

Comment: Alright, sounds reasonable, will do. Besides Lua is a fast enough engine. :d, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid special cases, make sure that the string always has `|`:

```
function test(s)
    s="|"..s
    print(s:match("^.*|(.*)$"))
end

test":ba"
test":ban user|:at"
test":ban user|:attention members|:kic"
```

Comment: That is a clever move pre-pending a `|` to the `s`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Many pattern matching problems that use separators can benefit from this uniformity. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/35826360/107090.